# How to Embed a iframe video in Web View Android?

Tags: android, video, webview, android-webview, embed

I want to embed the following video into an Android web view:
 https://www.espn.com.ar/core/video/iframe?id=6034792&endcard=false&omniReportSuite=wdgespg

I have tried different methods of the web view but without any results. No errors, I can view the player only but it doesn't play.

[image]

//MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
... 
android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

//CODE:

```
String html = String.format("<iframe src=\"%s\" width=\"340\" height=\"313\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>", url.getSrc());
wview.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://www.espn.com.ar", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

//OR

wview.loadUrl(url.getSrc());

//MY WEBVIEW:

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it is not a video 

https://www.espn.com.ar/core/video/iframe?id=6034792&endcard=false&omniReportSuite=wdgespg

Comment: Its a embed video

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check below code it is working fine with me, on manifest add
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

```
WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.myweb);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 8);
        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        webview.loadUrl("https://www.espn.com.ar");
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thats works! I've wasted too many hours searching the solution to this problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the internet permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```